# jquery autocompleter is not working for dynamically added textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLwm2/)
The jquery ui autocompleter is working on page load for first textbox, but after ading more textbox with same classname, then autocompleter is not working.

Can anyone help me please

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
 var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC" 
    ];
         $( ".lang" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });

        $('#addRow').click(
            function() {
                var curMaxInput = $('input:text').length;

                $('#rows li:first')
                    .clone()
                    .insertAfter($('#rows li:last'))
                    .find('input:text:eq(0)')
                    .attr({'id': 'ans' + (curMaxInput + 1),
                           'value': '',
                           'name': 'ans' + (curMaxInput + 1)
                          })
                    .parent()
                    .find('input:text:eq(1)')
                    .attr({
                        'id': 'ans' + (curMaxInput + 2),'value': '',
                        'name': 'ans' + (curMaxInput + 2)
                    });
                $('#removeRow')
                    .removeAttr('disabled');
                if ($('#rows li').length >= 5) {
                    $('#addRow')
                        .attr('disabled',true);
                }
                return false;
            });

        $('#removeRow').click(
            function() {
                if ($('#rows li').length > 1) {
                    $('#rows li:last')
                        .remove();
                }
                if ($('#rows li').length <= 1) {
                    $('#removeRow')
                        .attr('disabled', true);
                }
                else if ($('#rows li').length < 5) {
                    $('#addRow')
                        .removeAttr('disabled');

                }
                return false;
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the new `.lang` element you don't associate the autocomplete to it too, because the binding is done only on document ready.

So I created a function like this and then called in document ready, but also in `$('#addRow').click`:

```
function addAutocomplete() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC"];

    $(".lang").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
}
addAutocomplete();
```

I modified your code and create this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLwm2/2/). Hope this helps.